# Is the "Substring" method pure (in C#)? If yes, why isn't it annotated as [Pure]?

Tags: c#, pure-function

The `Substring` method of C#'s `string` class (which is also available in every other .Net language) does not seem to alter state and will always return the same value, given the same arguments.

So is it a "`pure`" method?

I'm asking, because in Microsoft's reference source code of the [`System.String` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs), many other public methods are annotated as `[Pure]` (like `Trim`, `Compare`, `IndexOf`, `Equals`), but the `Substring` method is not.

Comment: I took the freedom to change the question to ask what you really want to know, and added the missing reference to Microsoft's source. Please double check if I got your intentions right.

Comment: I wonder if `Substring` calling `InternalSubString`, the latter of which marked `unsafe` due to [pinning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning), would have explained why it cannot be marked as `Pure` despite meeting its practical requirements from a human understanding perspective.

Comment: Note that unlike the general definition of pure functions, PureAttribute only mentions that it shouldn't change any visible state.

Comment: @DocBrown, thanks, you got it right. My only note would be that I meant "every other programming language (like Java and etc)", as I suspect a `Substring` method is quite common, but I think it's OK.

Comment: @Vivelin, what does "shouldn't change any visible state" mean, exactly? Does it mean that the passed arguments (including the `string` on which the method is called) should not be changed, themselves?

Comment: @user85128: I would avoid to make generalizing statements about "every other programming language" - there are thousands of programming languages out there, and more string classes or string data types you or me can imagine. For example, I have still to deal with non-pure substring member function in an old C++ String class from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that Microsoft uses `[Pure]` exclusively in the context of Code Contracts (as opposed to, say, optimizing code during compilation or runtime). In this context, if the method doesn't make *visible* state changes, the method is pure. As simple as that.

When Code Contracts were introduced, the `[Pure]` attribute was added sporadically and sometimes inconsistently, and a series of methods which are pure didn't have this attribute. Back then I was working on several critical projects which required us to use Code Contracts, and I had to do a lot of wrappers around .NET Framework's assemblies just to add proper contracts, for instance saying that `Random.NextDouble` will always return a value which is greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. The same goes for `[Pure]`.

Chances are, some developers at Microsoft needed to work with `string.Trim` within the code covered by Code Contracts, and so it got its attribute, but nobody used `string.Substring`. Or there may be other considerations why the later didn't receive its well deserved attribute.

Anyway, if you rely on Code Contracts, create a wrapper and add the missing attribute.

If you don't rely on Code Contracts, ignore those attributes.

Comment: `[Pure]` has some other minor advantages outside Code Contracts - for example, some linters will pick up if the return value of a pure function isn't used.